# Pull one file out of a series of commits, into its own branch, preserving git history

Tags: git, github

I have a branch `feature/10/` which contains a new project under development with many files, one of the scripts in the branch `foo.py` has has turned into it's own sort of tangential side project that should not be in the `feature/10/` branch but should now go into a `feature/11/` branch, be finished and then pulled back into master. `foo.py` depends on files in master but does not interact with or depend on any of the new files in `feature/10/`.

Is there a way for me to create this new branch, copy in `foo.py` but nothing else AND preserve `foo.py`'s git history?

I could obviously just create a new branch and manually copy paste the file but this feels like it goes against the spirit of git as it cuts off the future development of `foo.py` from it's revision history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You didn't actually name your branches with backslashes in them, did you? I'm going to assume forward slashes.)

[git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) can do this.

```sh
git filter-branch $(git merge-base feature/10 feature/11)..feature/11 \
    --index-filter '
        BASE=$(git merge-base feature/10 feature/11)
        # Save the current state of foo.py
        FOO=$(git ls-files --stage -- foo.py)
        read -r mode object stage file <<<${FOO}
        # Set the entire tree back to the base state
        git read-tree ${BASE}^{tree}
        # Add the current foo.py to the tree
        git update-index --cacheinfo "${mode},${object},foo.py"
    ' \
    --prune-empty
```

Note, this will rewrite the `feature/11` branch. You can find the version before the rewrite as `original/feature/11`.